# How to validate that a user is accessing your url from the app store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm trying to save the development time of adding the user creation logic in an iOS app, and am considering this scenario: say a user purchases your app through the app store. Via the app, you give them a url that lets them create a signon for your site (since they have purchased the app).

How could you validate that the signup was legit (besides the URL)? Does Apple provide some kind of id which you could check the user against?

Edit: Another option would be to provide an additional button that says "Sign up", in addition to the current "Sign in" button. This would take a little more time, though.

Edit 2: Change to make non-opinion based.

Comment: You should have the transaction ID of the app purchase in the app receipt. Is what you're trying to validate that the call to your website is coming from a legit app purchaser?

Comment: Yes. We have an app that exists on both Android and the iPhone, which was previously available to companies which we're now making available to consumers. But the only current way to get a valid sign on is through the web site, where we've set up a pay option. However, if they've paid for an app already, we don't want to charge.

Answer (score 0):

What if you take your app's receipt and send it directly to your server?

```
NSString *receiptPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path];
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:receiptPath];
NSString *encodedReceipt = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NULL];
// Send the encodedReceipt to your server
```

You server can validate the receipt, use the (original) transactionId for the app itself as a unique key, and credit the user.